# Is there any way to slide left and right in jQuery without using jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery

Can you please tell me is there any way to slide left and right in jQuery without using jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile. Actually there is a way to slideup and slidedown. But there is not slide left and right?

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Jwkw6/1/

```
$(function() 
{  
    $('.specialist_pagecontent').eq(0).addClass("active").animate({ left : 0 }, 500);
    $('.specialist').click(function() {  
        $('.specialist_pagecontent').filter(".active").removeClass("active").stop(true).animate({ left : '-100%' }, 500); 
        $('.selected-specialist').removeClass('selected-specialist');
        $(this).addClass('selected-specialist');
        $('.specialist_pagecontent').eq($(this).index('.specialist')).addClass("active").stop(true).animate({ left : 0 }, 500);
    });  
});
```

Hope it helpful for you